# how hidden report power bi by check conditon ISFILTER

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I want hidden report power bi  if user not  define filter query string parameters in the URL
because i don't want user see data of all rows

[Power BI-Service-URL-Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters)

[isFiltered-Function-DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/dax/isfiltered-function-dax)

Comment: URL parameters aren't a security feature.  Try Row-Level Security: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls